# Bower: Where do those .map files come from?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, bower

I recently started working with Bower and I love it (how could I live without it?)

But when I install say bootstrap, I have a bunch of files downloaded in `bower_components`, which is cool.

But when I load my html page, I receive a 404 error: `http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map was not found`.

That is not the actual path I serve it from, hence the not found error is normal.

But I don't understand **where does this file is required from** and **what is its purpose**. Could you help me on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .map files are CSS [source maps](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors) distributed with bootstrap for use with certain browsers' developer tools.
If you are using the Chrome developer tools, the CSS source map files allows you to live-edit your bootstrap Less source files in the Sources panel, and view the results without having to leave DevTools or refresh the page.
You can see the reference to the CSS source map at the bottom of the bootstrap.css file:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */
```

You can configure the Chrome DevTools not to use CSS map files (DevTools Settings > Turn off Enable CSS source maps) or just remove the comment from the bootstrap CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with bower, it's simply the Chrome Developer Tools trying to find source maps to help with debugging.

You can open Chrome dev tools preferences and turn that option off for css maps and also javascript maps.